# How to create foreign key relationship in Entity Framework CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I'm new to Entity Framework, which I'm using for an ASP.NET MVC4 project.  I'm trying to create a foreign key relationship and am not having much success.  The problem may be in my seed data, which I'm not sure how to restructure from an earlier attempt to get this working.

Here are my two classes:

```
public class HardwareType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(128)]
        public string HType { get; set; }
        public int HardwareId { get; set; }
        public virtual Hardware Hardware { get; set; }


    }
```

and

```
public class Hardware
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //public int HardwareId { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<HardwareType> HardwareType { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my sample seed data:

```
protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        var loc = new List<Location> {
            new Location { LocationName = "Paradise Lane" },
            new Location { LocationName = "81st Street" }
        };
        loc.ForEach(l => context.Locations.Add(l));

        var type = new List<SoftwareType> {
            new SoftwareType { SType = "Suite" }
        };
        type.ForEach(t => context.SoftwareTypes.Add(t));

        var pub = new List<SoftwarePublisher> {
            new SoftwarePublisher { Publisher = "Adobe" },
            new SoftwarePublisher { Publisher = "Apple" },
            new SoftwarePublisher { Publisher = "Microsoft" }
        };

        var soft = new List<Software> {
            new Software { Title = "Adobe Creative Suite", Version = "CS6", SerialNumber = "1234634543", Platform = "Mac", Notes = "Macs rock!", PurchaseDate = "2012-12-04", Suite = true, SubscriptionEndDate = null, SeatCount = 0, Locations = loc.Where(s => s.LocationName == "Paradise Lane").ToArray(), Types = type.Where(s => s.SType == "Suite").ToArray(), Publishers = pub.Where(s => s.Publisher == "Adobe").ToArray() },
            new Software { Title = "Microsoft Office", Version = "2012", SerialNumber = "34252345", Platform = "PC", Notes = "PCs stink!", PurchaseDate = "2012-11-04", Suite = true, SubscriptionEndDate = null, SeatCount = 0, Locations = loc.Where(s => s.LocationName == "81st Street").ToArray(), Types = type.Where(s => s.SType == "Suite").ToArray(), Publishers = pub.Where(s => s.Publisher == "Microsoft").ToArray() },
            new Software { Title = "Apple iLife", Version = "2012", SerialNumber = "54675747564", Platform = "Mac", Notes = "Macs still rock!", PurchaseDate = "2012-12-04", Suite = true, SubscriptionEndDate = null, SeatCount = 0, Locations = loc.Where(s => s.LocationName == "Paradise Lane").ToArray(), Types = type.Where(s => s.SType == "Suite").ToArray(), Publishers = pub.Where(s => s.Publisher == "Apple").ToArray() }
        };
        soft.ForEach(s => context.Software.Add(s));

        var manuf = new List<Manufacturer> {
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "SonicWall" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Cisco" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Barracuda" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Dell" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "HP" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Maxtor" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "LaCie" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "APC" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Intel" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "D-Link" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Western Digital" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Quantum" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Seagate" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Apple" },
            new Manufacturer { ManufacturerName = "Canon" },
        };

        var device = new List<DeviceType> {
            new DeviceType { DType = "Network Device"},
            new DeviceType { DType = "Other"}
        };

        var htype = new List<HardwareType> {
            new HardwareType { HType = "PC" },
            new HardwareType { HType = "Monitor" },
            new HardwareType { HType = "Printer" },
            new HardwareType { HType = "Miscellaneous" }
        };

        var hard = new List<Hardware> {
            new Hardware { AssetTagId = "2134", Type = device.Where(h => h.DType == "Network Device").ToArray(), Manufacturer = manuf.Where(h => h.ManufacturerName == "SonicWall").ToArray(), ServiceTagId = "5243", SerialNumber = "3456", ProductNumber = "2345", PurchaseDate = "2012-10-23", WarrantyExpiration = "2012-11-12", WarrantyType = "NBD", Location = loc.Where(h => h.LocationName == "Paradise Lane").ToArray(), Notes = "Scrapped",  HardwareType = htype.Where(h => h.HType == "Monitor").ToArray()},
            new Hardware { AssetTagId = "2134", Type = device.Where(h => h.DType == "Network Device").ToArray(), Manufacturer = manuf.Where(h => h.ManufacturerName == "SonicWall").ToArray(), ServiceTagId = "5243", SerialNumber = "3456", ProductNumber = "2345", PurchaseDate = "2012-10-23", WarrantyExpiration = "2012-11-12", WarrantyType = "NBD", Location = loc.Where(h => h.LocationName == "Paradise Lane").ToArray(), Notes = "Scrapped",  HardwareType = htype.Where(h => h.HType == "PC").ToArray() },
            new Hardware { AssetTagId = "2134", Type = device.Where(h => h.DType == "Network Device").ToArray(), Manufacturer = manuf.Where(h => h.ManufacturerName == "SonicWall").ToArray(), ServiceTagId = "5243", SerialNumber = "3456", ProductNumber = "2345", PurchaseDate = "2012-10-23", WarrantyExpiration = "2012-11-12", WarrantyType = "NBD", Location = loc.Where(h => h.LocationName == "Paradise Lane").ToArray(), Notes = "Scrapped",  HardwareType = htype.Where(h => h.HType == "PC").ToArray() }
        };
        hard.ForEach(h => context.Hardwares.Add(h));

        base.Seed(context);

    }
```

How do I structure this so the foreign key relationship works.  Right now, I get this error: `Unable to set field/property HardwareType on entity type CIT.Models.Hardware. See InnerException for details.`

The inner exception is: `An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type 'CIT.Models.HardwareType[]'`.

Comment: please post error detail from inner exception.

Comment: An item cannot be removed from a fixed size Array of type 'CIT.Models.HardwareType[]'.

Comment: are you inserting a new row in `new Hardware { ...`?

Comment: can you post complete code here?

Comment: I added the sample data which includes a lot of other fields.  What else do you need?

Comment: what are `device`,`manuf` and `htype`?

Comment: See above.  I posted the entire seed data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21781/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-sehummel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing you'r tables structure like this :

```
public class Hardware 
{ 
public int Id { get; set; } 
. 
. 
. 
public HardwareTypeId { get; set; } 
public virtual HardwareType hardwareType {get;set;} 

}
```

and HardwareType :

```
public class HardwareType 
{ 
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string TypeName {get;set;} 
}
```